# I have problem with CSS position in IE7

Tags: html, css

I have problem with CSS position in IE7. here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/HXcM4/30/  input, and tooltip span is not moving with scroll bar in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok combined with oddy's fix for your javascript, to fix the bug in IE7 with the scrolling you just need to add `position: relative` to the `.mainDiv` rule.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/HXcM4/48/

Comment: tooltip span should be absolute and it need to scroll with scrollbar..http://jsfiddle.net/HXcM4/44/

Comment: it is working fine in jsfiddle but in my application not working... how can i sent the my HTML file...

Comment: hi... here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/G9tuV/6/   pin instructions and tooltip are not moving with scroll...

Answer (score 2):

As for jsfiddle error, check it out again, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HXcM4/44/).

Comment: Tnq. But i want the span should be scrool with scroolbar in ie7